# How to mock static block using Mockito in TestNG?

Tags: spring, testng

How to mock this static block using TestNG? Thanks!

```
static AnnotationConfigApplicationContext applicationContext;
static { applicationContext = new AnnotationConfigApplicationContext(Abc.class); }
```